# Meta Title from Region A is showing in SERP of Region B with Region B URL

Tags: seo, multilingual, internationalization

So, we have this multilingual and multi-regional website with every region on their specific subdomain.

The content on the websites is more or less the same except for a few changes. It's not duplicate though.

The problem is, when I open Google of Region A and enter my query, the results shown have the URL from Region A but `<title>` from Region B.

I have checked the implementation of `hreflang` attributes and they are fine. I am not sure what could be the problem; does anyone have any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Does the site use any conditional redirection based on user IP address or `Accept-Language`? Have there been any recent changes, e.g., content updates, URL migrations, etc.? What do you see in Google's cache?

Comment: No. The site is not using conditional redirection based on the IP address of the user. The Accept-Language tag has the following value as the default for all the regions and languages: 

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ur;q=0.6

We did move the site to HTTPS from HTTP. 

The Google cache shows the URL from Region B but the Search Result shows the URL from Region A

Answer (score 1):

I thank that this problem is indexing. For better solution you can go to Google webmaster tools/ Search Console >> Crawl >> Fetch as Google & submit these pages/sub-domain than wait while. Hope that your problem will be solve.

For example please check attached screenshot. [image]